# Content Query Web part for SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, modern-experience, content-query-web-part, 2019, sitepages

Is there a web part that is similar to the Content Query web part in SharePoint 2010, for SharePoint 2019 on-premises?

Comment: check SharePoint out of the box highlighted content web part: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd. Let me know if it meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use content query web part from SPFx sample gallery which does have similar functionality like classic content query web part.

https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-content-query-onprem

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  Have you used that web part on a Sharepoint on-prem site?  My developer is having issues installing it on our environment (we just have standard, not enterprise).

Comment: I have used in both the environment but not recently. I have used it before 2 years I would say

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct replacement of Content Query web part available in SharePoint 2019 modern experience.

Check if **Highlighted content web part** in modern experience meets your requirements. Highlighted content web part is kind of simplified version of the old Content Search web part.

If it does not work for you, you can find list of all available web parts in SharePoint modern experience in below link and see which one works for you: [Using web parts on SharePoint pages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-web-parts-on-sharepoint-pages-336e8e92-3e2d-4298-ae01-d404bbe751e0) - few of them might not be available in SharePoint server 2019 (read documentation carefully)

If none of the SharePoint out of the box web part meets your requirements, you have to develop the custom web part on your own. You can develop custom web part for modern experience using SharePoint framework (SPFx).

Check these documentations:

1. [Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)
2. [SharePoint Framework development with SharePoint Server 2019 & SharePoint Server SE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2019-support)